# symfony2: selected value of choices fields

Tags: forms, symfony, selected

I get something strange with Symfony2 forms. I create a form with a propel entity, values are fine except the "select" (choices) field, that have no selected value.

I tried few tricks like:

```
$params['choices'] = array('N/A'=> 'N/A');
$params['data'] = array('N/A');
$params['preferred_choices'] = array('N/A');
```

Even with this, there is no preselected value. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data` attribute for default selected item.
`$param['data'] = 'N/A'`
This is part of the Abstract "field" type [?](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/field.html)

Fore example form,

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('category', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                0 => 'Books',
                1 => 'Electronics',
                2 => 'Hardware`

            ),
            'data' => 1
        ))
        ->getForm();
```

In this example when the form loads the option Electronics should be selected as default

Comment: Doing, I have the following error:

    Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\SimpleChoiceList::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\Users\ng4196c\Workspaces\inside\inside_portal\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType.php on line 176 and defined 

Indeed, the constructor is:

public function __construct(array $choices, array $preferredChoices = array())
    {
      ...

Comment: Could u please share your `form` builder

Comment: From my Type class:
$params = array(
                'required' => true,
            );
$params['choices'] = array('N/A' => 'N/A');
$params['data'] = 'N/A';
$formBuilder->add('name', 'choice', $params);

Comment: Please try with this,  $formBuilder->add('name', 'choice',
                        'required'=>true,
                        'choices'=>array('N/A' => 'N/A')
                        'data'=>'N/A');

Answer (score 0):

```
'empty_value' => 'Select Choice',

$builder->add('gender', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array('m' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female')
     'empty_value' => 'Select Choice',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem. There were 2 things:
* reloading with Firefox, the previously selected value seems to be kept, so I coulnd't really test the changes until I closed the current tab and reopened one;
* I passed a single dimension array as values for the "choice" field, so Symfony2 re-indexed it with integer and my entity string value couldn't be hydrated to the symfony2 integer value of the field.